# Understand the use of 'raise the stakes of'

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-in-context

I am reading a book Blue Ocean Strategy. There was this sentence in the book:

> *Placing the kingpins in a fishbowl greatly raises the stakes of inaction.*

The problem with sentence is that everywhere in the book it is mentioned that it is a positive activity. But this particular sentence is completely opposite. What I have understood from the sentence is that placing the important people (kingpins) in a fishbowl (transparent meetings) increases the chances of inactivity. Help me if my interpreting it correctly. Below is the link to the paragraph.

[link to the paragraph](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=BaATDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=placing%20the%20kingpins%20in%20a%20fishbowl&source=bl&ots=aNR_YOhXMS&sig=ACfU3U0k_frge21iEP0lmDd8zqNpgWuLMA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7quTd8_7jAhVSHLkGHXjgA_oQ6AEIFTAE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are reading this the wrong way around.

"Raising the stakes" means making (something) riskier, and therefore in this case the assumption is that it will consequently make (that thing: inactivity) **less** frequent.

Comment: This would not be my interpretation. But that may depend on context.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to see the entire context of your sentence. However, my interpretation is that inaction is undesirable, and the risk of continuing inaction increases if the "kingpins in a fishbowl" strategy fails to produce results. This makes sense, as positions may harden or lines drawn as a result of a failed meeting where the leaders would look appear weak to reverse their position. Which is why typically, you don't have leaders meet until a framework of a deal is hashed out by negotiators.